# Image mask using dataurl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting to take an image that I created by changing pixel data and use it as a mask. I guess the big question is how can I turn a dataUrl into an image so I can use it ask a mask. As I see it the dataurl is a base64 image. I need to get the real image from the base64.

I am currently trying to use [Ben Barnett Canvas Utility](https://github.com/benbarnett/Canvas-Mask) for the masking. I am open to using something else to mask with if it can use a dataUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the base64 data for the image, and you need an Image object. All you need to do is:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = dataurl;
```

Comment: I tried that I think it must be something with my masking library.